# Dyld Error Message: 'Library not loaded: @executable_path/../../../libsteam_api.dylib'

Tags: macos, dyld

I tried to open this app and it doesn't launch, I have an iMac 10.14.6 Mojave.

Dyld Error Message:

```
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../../../libsteam_api.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/*/hoi4.app/Contents/MacOS/hoi4
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0):

the full problem details: 
Process:               hoi4 [86532]
Path:                  /private/var/folders/*/hoi4.app/Contents/MacOS/hoi4
Identifier:            hoi4
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           hoi4 [86532]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2020-05-10 22:37:49.961 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G103)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        6645D1F3-8FAD-CA5B-F13D-3FE36AB40479

Sleep/Wake UUID:       A4502BA6-6019-4815-9043-DC06F224B398

Time Awake Since Boot: 1100000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       280000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Notes:                 Translocated Process

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../../../libsteam_api.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/*/hoi4.app/Contents/MacOS/hoi4
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
   0xbb000 -  0x150bfeb + (??? - ???) <06048252-5295-3E17-8586-B7ED261AE338> /var/folders/*/hoi4.app/Contents/MacOS/hoi4
0xc0151000 - 0xc018de2b  dyld (655.1.1)  /usr/lib/dyld